# Передача массива данных типа String в другие Activity

Tags: java, android, массивы, парсер, jsoup

У меня есть 2-а Activity CovidCountryDetail и MapFragment в которых есть метод парсинга данных он занимает 5-6 секунд и после этого отображает данные на Activity меня не устраивает то что оно так долго парсить потому я решил создать загрузочный экран перед запуском приложения который будет висеть где-то 5-6 секунд и за это время парсить данные (то есть перенести метод из тех двух Activity на этот) после завершения парсинга передавать их в эти Activity (CovidCountryDetail и MapFragment). Парсинг записивается в одномерный массив resultRegions типа String. Как мне передать их в мои 2-а Activity? Intent не подойдет так как там нужно вызывать Activity в которое хочешь передать данные, а мне нужно просто передать данные в Activity CovidCountryDetail и MapFragment чтобы у них в переменной resultRegions уже были данные переданные мной с Activity загрузочного экрана. **Как мне это сделать?**

Сам загрузочный экран:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    private final int TIME_TO_OFF = 5000;
    private Document doc;
    private Thread secondThread;
    private Runnable runnable;
    volatile String[] resultRegions;
    private static final String TAG = com.modus.trackcovid19.ui.country.CountryFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

        initThread();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent main = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                SplashScreen.this.startActivity(main);
                SplashScreen.this.finish();
            }
        }, TIME_TO_OFF);
    }

    private void initThread() {
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getWeb();
            }
        };
        secondThread = new Thread(runnable);
        secondThread.start();
    }

    private String getRegionName(String name) throws IOException {
        if (name.equals("Kiev")) {
            return "Kiev,50.4547,30.5238";
        }
        Geocoder geocoder1 = new Geocoder(this, Locale.US);
        List<Address> regionSearch = geocoder1.getFromLocationName(name, 1);
        Address address = regionSearch.get(0);
        List<Address> regionSearch2 = geocoder1.getFromLocation(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude(), 1);
        Address address1 = regionSearch2.get(0);
        Log.d(TAG, "Region " + address1.getAdminArea() + "," + address1.getLatitude() + "," + address1.getLongitude());
        return address1.getAdminArea() + "," + address1.getLatitude() + "," + address1.getLongitude();
    }

    private void getWeb() {
        try {
            String url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic_in_Ukraine";
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements table = doc.getElementsByTag("tbody");
            Element myTable = table.get(2);
            Elements rowsTable = myTable.children();
            rowsTable.remove(rowsTable.size() - 1);
            rowsTable.remove(0);

            resultRegions = new String[myTable.childrenSize() - 2];
            for (int i = 1; i < myTable.childrenSize() - 1; i++) {
                String[] result = getRegionName(myTable.children().get(i).child(0).text()).split(",");
                resultRegions[i - 1] = result[0] + "," + myTable.children().get(i).child(1).text().replaceAll(",", "") + "," + myTable.children().get(i).child(2).text() + "," + myTable.children().get(i).child(3).text() + "," + result[1] + "," + result[2];
                Log.d(TAG, "Array: " + resultRegions[i - 1]);
            }
            //Здесь хочу передавать resultRegions в другие Activity
            Log.d(TAG, "Array length: " + resultRegions.length);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Circassian так такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Какая промежуточная активити?
Запускаешь активити, дергаешь сервис в презентере. Пока идет запрос и парсятся данные, показываешь прогресс или скелетон. Но если уж хочется с промеж активити, то ничто не мешает передать данные в интент. Или кешируй в базу данных. И еще, может лучше Retrofit и RX, чем вот это вот всё?

Comment: @Circassian После загрузочного экрана идет MainActivity в котором подключается nav menu в которое входит HomeFragment, CountryFragment и MapFragment (из CountryFragment  можно перейти в  CovidCountryDetail )

Comment: Это потрясающе) Короче, передавай в интент или кешируй, что является более правильным.